# Ubuntu - Changing banner-text on and restarting gdm results in login loop

Tags: 18.04, login

I've tried to change the banner-text on my personal computer. When I restart gdm - I get kicked out of session of course - it results in a login loop.
It seems off, because the screensaver "does not lie across the screen"...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Any log files I could look at?

Comment: How did you turn on banner text?

Comment: I tried turning on using `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`, with the commands `banner-message-enable=true` and  `banner-message-text='MY COMPUTER'`.

Comment: Ok so are you able to revert the changes from tty? I suspect `true` is to be `"true"`